# OpenText LiveLink : How can use ImpersonateUser function?

Tags: java, authentication, impersonation, opentext, livelink

I'd like to have from an admin user the context of the current loggin user.
For that, I use the admin token to have the current one with the function impersonateUser() because I don't have the password of the user.

I have the following error when I call the impersonateUser() on the Authentication object :
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: OTDS username and password are required.

Here my example :

```
URL authLocation = new URL("http://localhost:8080/les-services/services/Authentication?wsdl");
String aToken = WebServiceUtil.getAuthenticationToken(authLocation, username, password);//admin token
OTAuthentication fOTAuth = new OTAuthentication();
fOTAuth.setAuthenticationToken(aToken);
com.opentext.livelink.service.core.Authentication auth = webServiceUtil.getAuthenticationService(authLocation);             
String token = auth.impersonateUser(newUser);
fOTAuth.setAuthenticationToken(token);
```

I also found a class ImpersonateUser but I don't know how to use it :

```
ImpersonateUser impUser = new ImpersonateUser();
impUser.setUserName(newUser);
```

Do you have any advice ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Here are the [docs](https://knowledge.opentext.com/knowledge/cs.dll/fetch/-15106263/15106294/15106295/17990637/62345549/javadoc/com/opentext/livelink/service/core/Authentication_JAXWS.html#impersonateUser-java.lang.String-) for the `ImpersonateUser()` method.

Comment: Sadly, I don't have access to the KC.